# Error al calcular el Análisis del Componente Principal (PCA) de un array

Tags: python, array

Muy buenas es mi primera publicación en la página así que cualquier comentario o correción se lo agradezco.

A partir de unos cálculos y funciones obtengo una lista `l` donde cada sublista tiene la estructura de `l[0]`. A esa sublista quiero aplicarle el PCA para reducir su dimensión a dos. `[1,2,3,9]` serían los datos que obtengo para el año `[1998]`. La idea es reducir la dimensión y representar el punto respecto a dicho año.

```
import numpy     
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

for j in range(len(s)):
l.append([[s[i][j] for i in range(len(s))],[r[j]]])

pca=PCA(2)
l[0]=[[1, 2, 3, 9], [1998]]
l[0]=numpy.array(l[0],dtype=object)
pca.fit(l)
```

El error que me da es:

> "ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence."*

La sublista se identifica como:

```
l[0]=array([list([1, 2, 3, 9]), list([1998])], dtype=object)
```

Muchas gracias por adelantado.

Comment: Me parece a simple vista que no está importanto numpy

Comment: Sí lo está importando, no lo había puesto en el código.

Comment: Ni idea del tópico sklearn o PCA, pero.. ¿no es un poco raro que la lista `l` no tenga el mismo número de elementos en sus dos sub-listas? ¿Qué tipo de array va a crear `numpy` con una entrada como esa? Si cambias `[1998]` por `[1,9,9,8]` ya funciona (aunque, repito, ni idea de lo que estoy haciendo). Por si es de ayuda

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/406255/valueerror-setting-an-array-element-with-a-sequence)